# 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'replace' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript

```
if(theCurrentLength == 0)
    {
        theCurrentStory++;
        theCurrentStory      = theCurrentStory % theItemCount;
        theStorySummary      = theSummaries[theCurrentStory].replace(/&quot;/g,'"');
        theTargetLink        = theSiteLinks[theCurrentStory];
        theAnchorObject.href = theTargetLink;
        thePrefix            = theLeadString;
    }
```

What's the problem the above properties?

Comment: In this case replace property works well, maybe ***theSummeries*** is _undefined_.

Answer (score 3):

> What is the problem in replace poperty ?

There is no problem with it. The problem is that

```
theSummaries[theCurrentStory]
```

...returns `undefined` (or `null`, but probably `undefined`).

This suggests that if `theSummaries` is an array, `theItemCount` is not equal to `theSummaries.length`, and so you're ending up with `theCurrentStory` being an invalid index. When you index into an array with an invalid index, you get back `undefined`. You could just use `theSummaries.length` directly:

```
if(theCurrentLength == 0) // <== Does that really make sense?
{
    theCurrentStory      = (theCurrentStory + 1) % theSummaries.length;
    theStorySummary      = theSummaries[theCurrentStory].replace(/&quot;/g,'"');
    theTargetLink        = theSiteLinks[theCurrentStory];
    theAnchorObject.href = theTargetLink;
    thePrefix            = theLeadString;
}
```

Alternately, if the index is valid, it's possible to store `undefined` in an array entry. The only way to be sure is to use the debugger built into your browser and step through the code, looking at the values of the variables as you do.